# contains in xpath only checks first match

Tags: xpath

Taking this xml piece as example:

```
<list>
  <element>
    <title>Element 1</title>
    <group>Group 1</group>
  </element>
  <element>
    <title>Element 2</title>
    <group>Group 1</group>
  </element>
  <element>
    <title>Element 3</title>
    <group>Group 1</group>
    <group>Group 2</group>
  </element>
  <element>
    <title>Element 4</title>
    <group>Group 2</group>
    <group>Group 3</group>
  </element>
</list>
```

To get all groups I use the following xpath:

```
//group/text()
```

and it works fine -I remove duplicates later in python using a set as I don't know if I can do it with xpath-. But When I want to get the elements that contain "Group 3" I try the following xpath:

```
//element[contains(group/text(), "Group 3")]
```

and I get an empty result. While when I search elements that contain "Group 1" with:

```
//element[contains(group/text(), "Group 1")]
```

I get the correct result with 3 elements. And if I look for "Group 2" I get a wrong result with only one element.

What I'm not taking into account? How can I make those searches by group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` can only test, if a string occurs in another string.  `group/text()` is not a string, it is a set/sequence of nodes.

You can use

```
//element[group/text() = "Group 1"]
```

Comment: Better still is `//element[group = "Group 1"]`. It's best to avoid using `text()`, not only because it's usually unnecessary, but also because it's sometimes wrong - for example it won't work if the XML document contains comments mixed with the text.